# Scan input with UTF-8 in Java

Tags: java, utf-8, java.util.scanner

I am trying to find a way to get values actually typed into a variable so I can output them into a file.
The problem is that the scanner doesn't recognize the Czech letters such as "ř ; á ; ž ; š" etc.
Here is the code sample:

```
String jmeno;
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in, "utf-8");
jmeno = input.next();
```

What I type:

> Šárka

What is stored in variable jméno:

> ??rka

The "?" represent junk characters, with the question marks in black boxes.
How should I adjust the code, so that the letters are recieved correctly by the variable?

Also the computer I am using has EN(US) system encoding.

Comment: The variable probably stores the correct values, but they cannot be printed/displayed in your environment. How do you output the String?

Comment: Are **sure** it is rubbish? Some Fonts simply don't have the code points to be rendered a character, thus replacing with "?".

Comment: Did println and it goes out ?árka with the iso verision trying for caps utf-8

Comment: Nope UTF-8 not working either

Comment: the output is written on screen by system.out.println and also into the file using buffered output stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `new Scanner(System.in)`. This uses the default operating system's encoding, the same as System.in uses. The String (as always) contains the Unicode version, which you then may write to a file using

```
new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(...), "UTF-8")
```

or other (simpler) methods.

Comment: This might be the problem. I am using english(US) machine but I want my program to recognize czech letters as well. Is this the issue? the Program will be used in czech computers only. So default system encoding will always be Czech

Comment: System.in is going native, hence a problem. Now an IDE console might just be something different. Best would be _not_ to use System.in. On Windows you might have success with **"Windows-1252"** - MSWindows Latin-1 - instead of "ISO-8859-1" - official Latin-1.

Comment: How can I check quickly if the code is could run on czech region PC?

Comment: 99.99% certain that there is no problem in Czechia.

Comment: Thanks I put my head on the block for trusting you so I hope its ok :) You rock by the way!

Comment: I'll send a treat if as-is reading of System.in does not work... (Prerequisite) `System.getProperty("file.encoding")` must not have been tampered with.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to try

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-1");
```

EDIT:
As you said some characters are still not working consider trying:

```
Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in, "ISO-8859-2");
```

"ISO-8859-2" suprorts Czech [Check this for more information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-2)

Comment: Why would you suggest that? The question title seems to imply that the input is UTF-8.

Comment: Almost. It however doesn't store "ř" in variable. so Input šárka Output ?árka

Comment: Czech is latin2 AFAIK.

Comment: @Lance try "ISO-8859-2"

Answer (score 0):

*This should be a comment but sadly I don't have that privilege yet.*

When debugging (by outputing some text to a file, browser, or just watch them in an IDE), don't rush to say "it's not working because I get ? characters here".

Maybe it's just your IDE/system that can't display those utf-8 chars.

To be really sure, you can copy the outputted text from file/browser/debugger, then paste it to Notepad++ (or some other editor that has a hex editor), then use `view in hex`, if you see `0xefbfbd` (utf-8's "can't decode this" code), then it's broken. Otherwise everything's fine.